# Yum cannot install php addons

Tags: centos, php, yum

I had an issue with phpmyadmin so i uninstalled php and all it's addons and reinstalled it, but yum complains it can't install php-common:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.funet.fi
 * epel: mirror.yandex.ru
 * extras: ftp.funet.fi
 * updates: ftp.funet.fi
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.el7_1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                   Arch                                                  Version                                                           Repository                                           Size
=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 php-common                                                x86_64                                                5.4.16-36.el7_1                                                   base                                                563 k

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 563 k
Installed size: 3.8 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                                                 | 563 kB  00:00:00
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                         1/1
Error unpacking rpm package php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /etc/php.d/curl.ini: cpio: rename
  Verifying  : php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                         1/1

Failed:
  php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.el7_1

Complete!
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by removing /etc/php.d